# Solve 4*ABCD = DCBA in python

Tags: python

I'm still a beginner and I am trying to do the following exercise:

A, B, C, and D are all different digits. The number DCBA is equal to 4 times the number ABCD. What are the digits? Note: to make ABCD and DCBA conventional numbers, neither A nor D can be zero. Use a quadruple-nested loop.

Here's where I got stuck:

```
for A in range(0,9):
    for B in range(0,9):
        for C in range(0,9):
            for D in range(0,9):
```

How to solve 4*ABCD = DCBA using a quadruple-nested loop?

Comment: Can you compose a number out of these digits you already have?

Comment: Hint 2: If A and B are the digits of "AB", then the actual number is 10*A + B.

Comment: Why don't you just do this using math? Why do you need to program it? Is it an assignment to brute-force it with a program or something?

Comment: I think it's just an assignment to get comfortable using loops etc. as it is one from a beginners class

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there - the only thing you're missing is to convert the digits to a whole number, e.g., by multiplying them by their respective "place". BTW, if A and D can't be 0, you should exclude that from the range of values:

```
for a in range(1,9):
    for b in range(0,9):
        for c in range(0,9):
           for d in range(1,9):
               if 4* (1000 * a + 100 * b + 10 * c + d) == \
                  (a + 10 * b + 100 * c + 1000 * d):
                   print "a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d" % (a, b, c, d)
```

The result, by the way, is:

```
a=2 b=1 c=7 d=8
```

Answer (score 1):

The following prints all solutions, don't need a quadruple-nested loop:

```
    for i in range(1000,10000):
        if i==4*int(str(i)[::-1]):
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a constraint programming problem that can be solved like this:
need to pip install python-constraint

```
from constraint import *
problem = Problem()
l = range(10)
for v in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:
    problem.addVariable(v, l)
problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint())
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b, c, d : 4*(a*1000+ b*100+ c*10 + d) == 1000*d + 100*c + 10*b + a,
                      ("a", "b", "c", "d"))
print problem.getSolutions()
```

here the computation time is negligible but for more complex problems, the computation time might be way shorter than embedded loops because the search space is efficiently searched

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
for a in range(1,10):
  for b in range(0,10):
    for c in range(0,10):
        for d in range(1,10):
            q=str(a)
            w=str(b)
            e=str(c)
            r=str(d)
            t=(q+w+e+r)
            u=int(t)
            y=t[::-1]
            i=int(y)

            if u==4*i:
                print(i)
                print(u)
                print(u ,"=4*" ,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

mureiniks answer works for 4 digits since the answer does not include 9, but the loops should go to 10 since in Python `range(9)` is not the values of 0 to 9, but the values 0 to 8.

If you try for 5 digits the loops to 9 will not give you the answer "21978":

```py
for a in range(1,10):
    for b in range (0,10):
        for c in range(0,10):
            for d in range(0,10):
                for e in range(0,10):
                    num=a*10000+b*1000+c*100+d*10+e
                    mun=a+b*10+c*100+d*1000+e*10000
                    if 4*num == mun:
                        print("4*",num,"=",4*num," and mun ",mun)
```